# How to handle table data requests with RACCommands

Tags: reactive-cocoa

I have a ViewModel for a UITableView that holds an array of data elements. The UITableView implements a pull-to-refresh and infinite-scroll behavior. Data elements are requested via RestKit from a server in a paginated fashion which means I have to track the current page somehow. I created 2 separate RACCommands to differentiate between refreshs and infinite-scroll-loads where the refresh always loads page 0. The whole thing works but I don't like it and want to know if there is a better way to do this. Plus right now the 2 commands may be executed concurrently which is not intended.

```
@interface TableDataViewModel ()

@property(nonatomic, readonly) RestApiConnector *rest;
@property(nonatomic) int page;
@property(nonatomic) NSMutableArray *data;
@property(nonatomic) RACCommand *loadCommand;
@property(nonatomic) RACCommand *reloadCommand;

@end

@implementation TableDataViewModel

objection_requires_sel(@selector(rest))

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self configureLoadCommands];
        [self configureActiveSignal];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)configureActiveSignal {
    [self.didBecomeActiveSignal subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        if (!self.data) {
            [self.reloadCommand execute:self];
        }
    }];
}

- (void)configureLoadCommands {
    self.loadCommand = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {
        return [self.rest dataSignalWithPage:self.page];
    }];
    self.reloadCommand = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {
        return [self.rest dataSignalWithPage:self.page];
    }];
    self.loadCommand.allowsConcurrentExecution = FALSE;
    self.reloadCommand.allowsConcurrentExecution = FALSE;

    [self.reloadCommand.executionSignals subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        RAC(self, data) = [x map:^id(id value) {
            self.page = 0;
            return [value mutableCopy];
        }];
    }];

    [self.loadCommand.executionSignals subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        RAC(self, data) = [x map:^id(id value) {
            self.page++;
            if (self.data) {
                NSMutableArray *array = [self.data mutableCopy];
                [array addObjectsFromArray:value];
                return array;
            } else {
                return [value mutableCopy];
            }
        }];
    }];
}
@end
```

I just started using ReactiveCocoa, so I'd appreciate any other tips for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just started using ReactiveCocoa, so I'd appreciate any other tips for this.

If you only want one command or the other to execute at a time, one way to achieve this is to just use a single command (and disable concurrent execution, as you have already done):

```
1  const NSUInteger kLoad   = 0;
2  const NSUInteger kReload = 1;
3
4  - (void)configureActiveSignal {
5      @weakify(self);
6      RACSignal *dba = [[self.didBecomeActiveSignal filter:^(id _) {
7              @strongify(self);
8              return self.data;
9          }]
10          mapReplace:@( kReload )];
11
12      RACSignal *ls = [self.command rac_liftSelector:@selector(execute:) withSignals:dba];
13      [[ls publish] connect];
14  }
15  
16  - (void)configureCommand {
17      @weakify(self);
18      self.command = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithSignalBlock:^(NSNumber *loadOrReload) {
19              @strongify(self);
20              return RACTuplePack(loadOrReload, [self.rest dataSignalWithPage:self.page]);
21          }];
22
23      RAC(self, page) = [self.command.executionSignals reduceEach:^(NSNumber *loadOrReload, id _) {
24              @strongify(self);
25              return kReload == loadOrReload.integerValue ? @0 : @( ++self.page );
26          }];
27      RAC(self, data) = self.command.executionSignals reduceEach:^(NSNumber *loadOrReload, NSArray *data) {
28              @strongify(self);
29              if (kReload == loadOrReload.integerValue)
30              {
31                  return [data mutableCopy];
32              }
33              else
34              {
35                  NSMutableArray *ma = [self.data mutableCopy];
36                  [ma addObjectsFromArray:data]
37                  return ma;
38              }
39          }];
40
41      self.command.allowsConcurrentExecution = NO;
```

Nota bene, this is totally untested. But I hope it communicates the basic idea.

- You can infer from the code that there is only one command now, and its instance variable is named `command`. Instead of getting called with the array of data, it is now called with a constant to indicate whether it should load orreload, which you can see on line 18.
- **Line 5:** Your code had a lot of retain cycles. You can't strongly reference `self` from within a block that is strongly referenced by `self` (either directly, or via an indirect chain of object ownership). ReactiveCocoa comes with the `@strongify/weakify` macros to help make this less arduous. As you can see, any time you need to reference `self` within a block that is owned by a command (which is itself owned by `self`, thus the cycle), you need to create a weak reference to self and then use that inside the block. You use `@strongify` inside of the block to avoid a data race with ARC's release mechanism.
- **Line 6:** Transform the `didBecomeActive` notifications into executions of `self.command` with a parameter of `kReload` (this replaces your old `reloadCommand`), but only if `self.data != nil`, using `-filter:`.
- **Line 12:** Here's where you actually call `[self.command execute:]`, but you do this by lifting the selector onto the signal just created above. Presumably you have some other unshown code that used to execute `self.loadCommand`, you will need to adjust that to pass `@( kLoad )` instead.
- **Line 13:** The `-publish/connect` idiom is conventionally used when you want to subscribe to a signal without actually doing anything with its value. This isn't strictly necessary in RAC 2.x.
- **Line 18:** You can see that the command will call its signal block with a NSNumber now, that is, the constant that you have lifted up onto the signal created on line 6. However, where before the command returned just the data, it now returns a tuple containing both the input to `-execute:` and the data. This is because as you'll see below, downstream operations need access to both pieces of information.
- **Line 23:** Instead of using the `RAC()` macro inside of a signal subscription block (which is almost always an antipattern), you now use it directly in the `-configureCommand` method. Here we are saying that any time the command is executed, set `self.page` to either `0` or `++self.page`, depending on whether the command was executed with `kLoad` or `kReload`. The `-reduceEach:` operation is just a convenience to destructure the tuple being sent through the signal, and here we only care about the constant. **Note the side-effect of incrementing `self.page` in this `-reduceEach:` operation.** It's generally bad form to have side effects in your signal operations. The danger is that if something other than `RAC(self, page)` subscribes to the returned signal, the instance variable can be incremented more times than you would expect. It would be ideal if you could obtain the value of `self.page` from the source of data somehow, rather than tracking it in a global instance variable.
- **Line 27:** This is just a variation on what you just did on line 23, but instead of setting `self.page`, you're setting `self.data`. This time the `-reduceEach:` operation does need to use the second value in the tuple (the data), which is transformed appropriately for either `kLoad` or `kReload`, and then ultimately set on the ivar.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot in understanding the concepts. Found one little problem, the signal block for the command has to return a signal instead of a tuple. I used map/flatten to achieve this. Also took your advice of removing the page state.
See: https://gist.github.com/kuhnroyal/9760542

Comment: I too have just started with reactive cocoa. This example is awesome. However, I'm using reactive cocoa 4.1 and I can't get the example to compile ( I know you said it was untested @erikprice ).

RACCommand initWithSignalBlock now requires returning RACSIgnal so I'm stuck on how to pass the tuple through the execution signals.